# this.innerHTML in Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, this

js code snippet that goes like this:

```
function currency_change(value) {

  // change all currencies on the page
  $$('label.currency').each(function() {

    this.innerHTML = value;

  });
  alert(value);

}
```

I know `value` is correct and I know I'm traversing over each label.currency class, but I can't seem to change the `innerHTML` values of these elements.

I googled like crazy, but I can't figure out how to do this. I suspect something is wrong with `this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$$('label.currency').each(function(element) {
    element.update(value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$$('label.currency').invoke('update',value);
```

IE shows very poor performance when replacing complex DOM trees. In such cases remove the inner DOM before updating:

```
$$('label.currency').invoke('childElements').invoke('invoke','remove');
```

If it's one single Element you can say:

```
$('elementID').childElements().invoke('remove');
```